# npm MongoDB package installation fails on Windows

Tags: windows, node.js, mongodb

It says that it's "Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: mongo
db@0.9.8". Any ideas? (I have mongo installed and it runs fine)

```
C:\www\webhookit>npm install mongodb
npm WARN package.json ejs@0.6.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json webhookit-comment@0.0.3 No README data
npm WARN package.json webhookit-ejs@0.0.3 No README data
npm WARN package.json webhookit-http@0.0.5 No README data
npm WARN package.json webhookit-jsonparse@0.0.2 No README data
npm WARN package.json webhookit-objectbuilder@0.0.3 No README data
npm WARN package.json webhookit-jsonpath@0.0.3 No README data
npm WARN package.json webhookit-xml2js@0.0.2 No README data
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: mongo
db@0.9.8
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    linux,darwin,freebsd
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: ia32

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program File
s (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "mongodb"
npm ERR! cwd C:\www\webhookit
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.23
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\www\webhookit\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Ideas? Um, use linux, darwin, or freebsd?

Comment: Why would a package require the use of linux, darwin, or freebsd if mongo itself works fine?

Comment: The problem is not with mongodb, it is with the driver / connector with node. Apparently, this connector was not made to run on windows

Comment: Can I install it manually then?

Comment: I wrote a post on how to manually install and have MongoDB running on Windows, hope it helps: http://ricardodsanchez.com/2014/09/03/install-mongodb-service-on-windows-8/

Answer (score 0):

The `package.json` of [**webhookit**](https://github.com/neyric/webhookit/blob/master/package.json) explicitly states the *OS* `"os": ["darwin", "linux"],`

Hence you get the error message

`npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    linux,darwin,freebsd
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32`

Perhaps you can safely remove that line and the webhookit still function normally without such restriction of OS?